# Wrap text in a stack widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to wrap text that is used in a `Stack` widget.

This is what I have so far. If I wrap the `Text` with a `Container` and wrap that in an `Expanded` widget, it wraps but it doesn't apply the position anymore and it throws `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget`. Any suggestions?
`

```
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                ShaderMask(
                  shaderCallback: (rect) {
                    return LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
                    ).createShader(
                        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
                  },
                  blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',
                    height: 330,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 5.0,
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        widget.content.title.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex... (from doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).

Maybe it does not work with Stack.
Try putting it under a Column.
Or wrap to containers in the same column and use space between.

Comment: I need it in a Stack. The title has to be above the image, right where the gradient effect is.

Comment: Then try wrapping the Expanded in a Column